# Querying Linked Server in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Wondering if yall can help me resolving an error I'm receiving when using Invoke-Sqlcmd to query a linked server in powershell. Thank you for any help you might be able to provide!

Here's my code

```
$SQLServer = "SERVER1"
$database = "Database1"
$query = "

    SELECT
    a.id,
    a.location,
    a.name,
    b.office


    FROM [SERVER1].[Database1].[dbo].[Table1] a 

    LEFT JOIN [SERVER1].[Database1].[dbo].[Table2] b ON b.id = a.id 

"
 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $database -Query $query
```

Here's the error I receive:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote 
connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Comment: You're connecting to `SERVER1` to query a linked server from there to... `SERVER1`? Linked servers are typically to join data from server, say `SERVER1`, to a linked server _somewhere else_, e.g. `SERVER2`.

Comment: (As a different prompt, are you sure you're using linked servers at all? Did you try without the `[SERVER1].` prefix?)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I appreciate the response maybe that's what's causing my issue.  I'm trying to connect SERVER1 to a linked SERVER2.  In the example code i submitted, SERVER1 is the name of the linked-server i'd like to connect to.

Comment: But your PowerShell is _also_ trying to connect to `SERVER1` and I don't see `SERVER2` mentioned anywhere. You say "I'm trying to connect" but not being explicit enough, or explaining why you need a linked server. Can PowerShell connect to `SERVER1` and run a query there without the `SERVER1` prefix? Can PowerShell connect to `SERVER2` and run a query there without a server prefix? If PowerShell can connect to both servers, what are you actually trying to do and why does it need to involve linked servers?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience working with powershell and SQL I've been unable to get Invoke-SQL command to work properly. I have however used this method with much success.
You can change the integrated security to true and it will use the currently logged in Windows account to authenticate with the SQL server instead of providing the credentials in the script.

```
#creates connection, enter the SQL server host name, the user and password.

$connectionString = “Server=#SQLServer;uid=$User2; pwd=$pwdencrypt2;Integrated Security=False;”
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
                $connection.Open()

#This will be your query bulk insert as an example
                [string]$queryCL1 = "

BULK INSERT [Databasename].[dbo].[tablename]
FROM 'filepath'
WITH( 
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      FIRSTROW = 2 
    )"
#this uses the set variables to build and execute the command with execute reader

                $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
                $command.CommandText = $queryCL1
                $command.CommandTimeout=0
                $resultCL1 = $command.ExecuteReader()
```